# JDBC Connection to MySql error - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get an error when trying to connect with my MySql, here is my code:

```java
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_schema";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
```

And here is the error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
..etc
```

I have tried:

```java
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_schema","root",null);
```

Comment: It looks like you should specify a password, or is your password really a empty string?

Comment: What is your password ? did you try to login in console ?

Comment: I don't have a password

Answer (score -1):

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_schema";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", null);
```

as "" is marked as empty string not null.

also try to give

```
grant all privileges on new_schema.* to 'root'@'%'
```

Are you able to connect MySQL locally using?

```
mysql -u root -p
```

if you are not able to connect locally, then must be something wrong with your MySQL setup.
Also please take to take a backup before uninstalling the server

Try

1. Uninstall MYSQL server
2. Remove everything from the base folder/directory where MySQL is installed
3. Install a fresh MySQL server

Please elaborate more about the issue
Java code seems to be correct
Also, how are you connecting MySQL with Java code, is it via mysql-connector-XXXX.jar or something else?

Comment: Advising to reinstall mysql server without any backup of existing data just because of an access denied error message is a very bad practice! Asking clarification questions in an answer is also a bad practice. I know you don't have the right to comment, but still pls do not use  answers to ask questions.

Comment: I tried all of the things that you said, nothing worked, i typed mysql -u root -p
 and
"mysql is not recognized as a command.."